# how spring scheduler manages the time

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-scheduled

In my project, i have to run the scheduler method for every 15 seconds,I done that code successfully.I fetch and process 1000 records from the database while running the scheduler each time.But some times, processing takes more than 15  seconds that time new thread will created or execution starts once that thread is finished.

As per my knowledge new thread is not created.Only one thread is executing that scheduler.

Below is my sample testing code for identify only one thread is executing:

```
<bean id="printNumber" class="com.uniphore.PrintNumber">
    </bean>
    <task:scheduled-tasks>
        <task:scheduled ref="printNumber" method="execute"
            cron="*/1 * * * * ?" />
    </task:scheduled-tasks>
    public void execute() {
        int i = 1;
        while(i < 100000) {
            i++;
            LOGGER.trace("I is :: {}", i);
        }
     }
```

Here each time 1 to 100000 is printing.Eventhough the 1 second is over before printing 10000.so i assume only one thread is for schduler
Is it correct?

Comment: bring some code to the table man, or none can help you out....

Comment: ok i will add the code